# Uniqueness and existence, (Need help with translating a statement into logical symbols.)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that for every set $A$ there is a unique set $B \subseteq A$ such that for every set $C \subseteq A, B \Delta C = A\setminus C$.

I need help with translating the meaning of this statement into a sensible logical structure.

Could someone please help me simplify this statement into logical symbols? Thanks.

My attempt:

Goal?

$\forall A \exists ! B \subseteq A \forall C \subseteq A(B \Delta C  = A \setminus C)$. This one does't make any sense to me.

Alternatively?

$\forall A \exists ! B  ( B\subseteq A\wedge \forall C (C\subseteq A \to (B \Delta C  = A \setminus C))).$

Comment: $$\forall A\;\exists!B\subseteq A\;\forall C\subseteq A,\;\;B\Delta C=A\setminus C$$ I should note that this is basically unreadable, and is not preferred. Mixing in a healthy amount of text makes for better proof-writing.

Comment: Can you expand this expression for me? :o

Comment: Which part are you struggling to parse?

Comment: A quantifier followed by a subset. I don't know the definition for that expression.

Comment: Oh like $\forall C\subseteq A$? That, in english, translates to, for all subsets of $A$. It just is a concise notion to indicate what the for all is over.

Comment: Since I still don't fully understand this notation. Would you mind proving this statement for me with logical symbols only?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for. $\forall C\subseteq A, X$ is basically the same thing as $\forall C,\; C\subseteq A\to X$.

Comment: Your alternative is okay (I would go for that). I think that essential simplification is not possible. Also you can write $\cdots\exists!B\in\wp(A)\cdots$ instead of  $\cdots\exists!B\subseteq A\cdots$ but then operator $\wp$ is involved. Btw, the statement is true and $B=A$ satisfies.

Comment: Do you want to get rid of signs like $!,\subseteq,\Delta,\setminus$ and find a formula purely in quantors and relation $\in$ maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The exact logical formulation is not really the issue in the exercise. Just think about proving it.

The statement holds as we can take $B=A$ and then note that, whenever $C \subseteq A$:

$$B \Delta C  =A \Delta C = (A\setminus C) \cup (C\setminus A) = A \setminus C$$

The set $B$ is unique with that property, for if some $x \in A\setminus B$ existed, for $C=\{x\}$ we would have $x \in B \Delta C$ while $x \notin A \setminus C$, so the desired equality cannot hold for all $C$ that are subsets of $A$. So $A \subseteq B$ and the other inclusion holds by definition.

So $A=B$ is forced.